# MySQL - Inner join with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've problem finding records with conditions where. I would like to find all course, which have the flag/flags.

Records for the **course** table:

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| id | code |      name       |
+----+------+-----------------+
| 1  | JPA  | JPA Lorem ipsum |
| 2  | JSF  | Jsf lorem ipsum |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

Records for the **course_flags** table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | course_id | flag_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 1  | 1         | 1       |
| 2  | 1         | 2       |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

## My first query: (good)

```
 SELECT `course`.`id`, `course`.`name`  FROM `course` 
 INNER JOIN `course_flags`
 ON `course` .`id` = `course_flags`.`course_id`
 WHERE (`course_flags`.`flags_id` = 1)
```

Database returns:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      name       |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | JPA Lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------------+
```

## My second query for two conditions: (bad?)

```
 SELECT `course`.`id`, `course`.`name`  FROM `course` 
 INNER JOIN `course_flags`
 ON `course` .`id` = `course_flags`.`course_id`
 WHERE (`course_flags`.`flags_id` = 1 and `course_flags`.`flags_id` = 2)
```

Database returns:

```
null
```

I would like to receive:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      name       |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | JPA Lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------------+
```

Question how do I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want all courses that have all flags supplied.

You can do this by adding an or condition to the join then checking the number of flags is as you expect:

```
SELECT `course`.`id`, `course`.`name`  FROM `course` 
INNER JOIN `course_flags`
     ON `course` .`id` = `course_flags`.`course_id` 
     AND (`course_flags`.`flags_id` = 1 OR `course_flags`.`flags_id` = 2)
WHERE 
GROUP BY (course.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT course_flags.id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN course_flags AS cf
ON c.id = cf.course_id
WHERE cf.flags_id = 1 
   OR cf.flags_id = 2
```